# Ubuntu 22.04 apt-upgrade fail (libperl5.34, perl5, perl-base_5.34.0 dpkg error)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and I can't upgrade now. Here is the error:

```
**$ sudo apt upgrade**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon avahi-utils cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ipp-utils cups-ppdc cups-server-common fonts-opensymbol google-chrome-stable iptables libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7
  libavahi-glib1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libperl5.34 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libraw20 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-colibre
  libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-writer libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libxtables12 perl perl-base perl-modules-5.34 python3-uno python3.10
  python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal python3.10-venv tzdata uno-libs-private ure
69 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
63 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 0 B/233 MB of archives.
After this operation, 47,1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute package control information extraction (dpkg-deb): Input/output error
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.34_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute package control information extraction (dpkg-deb): Input/output error
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute package control information extraction (dpkg-deb): Input/output error
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.34_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: can you check if the disk still has some free space? $ df | egrep '^/'| grep -v loop "Input/output error" sounds like a disk/space problem. Kinds Regards
maniac__

Answer (score 0):

`Input/output error` is the key information.

Your storage device is not working properly.

Look up how to run a SMART Test on your storage device to verify if it is failing or faulty.

If it fails the SMART test, then replace that faulty/dying storage device. Yes, that's a painful thing to do.

It's also possible that your storage device is fine and passes the SMART test, but merely has some bad blocks. All storage devices accumulate those over time. Look up how to use `badblocks` to mark those off-limits to your system.